# Reset a form to its original state with a button

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, reset

[image]

I created a new button to reset the form which consists of
combobox,
textbox,
richtextbox,
disabled button

So, i created a utilities.cs class but its not working and gives an error.

*ERROR*: The type or namespace name 'ComboBox' could not be found.

```
namespace example
{
class Utilities
{
    public static void ResetAllControls(Mainform form)
    {
        foreach (Mainform control in form.Controls)
        {
            if (form is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)control;
                if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have `using System.Windows.Forms`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `ComboBox` out side the Form class, `ComboBox` is defined in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace so you need to add *using System.Windows.Form*.

```
using System.Windows.Forms; //You need this statement.
namespace example
{
 class Utilities
 {
    public static void ResetAllControls(Mainform form)
    {
        foreach (Mainform control in form.Controls)
        {
            if (form is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)control;
                if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }    
 }
}
```

**Edit**

If Utilities class is not in the WinForms project then you will need to add reference to `System.Windows.Forms` this article [Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) will guide you to add reference.

Comment: Not working...its shows an error as Error: Cannot convert type 'example.Mainform' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think you need to add the dll as well.

Comment: Should it not be foreach(Control control in form.Controls ? If (control is ComboBox ) ?
Also if you wish to have this as a separate util class, it needs to be public, and I would have Form as type of the parameter for reusability.